# What kinds of Metallic Dragons were ever shown in D&D products?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, lore, dragons

Everyone knows the iconic metallic dragons that come in almost every single core monster book, Gold, Silver, Bronze, Copper, Brass. Let's call those the **"core five"**

There were some others, like dunno *Steel, Iron, Platinum, Electrum, Uranium(?)*, and what else...

What kinds of metallic dragons other than the "core five" were shown in D&D products?
What were their ecologies and demeanors?
In what worlds did they debut/existed?

Comment: While I think this may be too broad, there is likely a finite number of metallic dragons (as you note) so it may fit within scope. [Suggest you include Bahamut as one of the core](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/24654/22566), as the Platinum dragon has been with us since Greyhawk supplement to OD&D

Comment: Having done the work for 3.5e, I think I agree with @KorvinStarmast—too broad. For one person to try to do the same for every edition, and then to put it into one answer, that would be too much, I think.

Comment: I think you could probably get away with separate questions for each edition, though.

Comment: @KRyan Ok senpai.

Answer (score 7):

In D&D 3.5e, the most-complete listing of true dragons is in *Races of the Dragon* on pages 70-72. This list gives the stats of the half-dragon version of every dragon, and claims to be complete. However, the only apparent metallic dragons on the list are those from *Monster Manual*. Even other good-aligned dragons, namely the battle dragon, Oceanus dragon, and radiant dragon, don’t seem to be metallic. The list does mention the rust dragon from *Draconomicon*, which is arguably sort of metallic, but it’s notably lawful **non**-good.

Anyway, the *Races of the Dragon* list misses the steel dragon that you noted; the steel dragon was published in *Dragons of Faerûn* in August 2006, while *Races of the Dragon* was in January of the same year. Still, January 2006 covers a whole lot of the 3.5 life-cycle, so we do not have to search as many books to find other dragons. *Monster Manual II* and *III* are covered by *Races of the Dragon*, for instance, and *Monster Manual IV* has no dragons while *Monster Manual V* has only specific named individual dragons of existing types, not new types of dragons. Similarly, *Dragon Magic* focuses on magic available to and/or derived from dragons, and while it has many options for dragons, it does not have any new dragons itself.

*Magic of Incarnum* is semi-notorious for having a dragon, the incarnum dragon, that *Races of the Dragon* missed—it was published in September 2005, not long before *Races of the Dragon*, but nonetheless. (This is semi-notorious because its absence has been used as justification for not seeing dragonwrought kobold’s absence in the list as definitive of anything.)

So OK, every book published since September 2005, then. Using [HeyICanChan’s handy list](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/36990/4563), then:

| Year | Month | Title | Checked? | Findings |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2005 | Sep | *Magic of Incarnum* | ✓ | incarnum |
|  |  | *Sons of Gruumsh* |  |  |
|  | Oct | *Heroes of Horror* | ✓ |  |
|  |  | *Magic of Eberron* |  |  |
|  | Nov | *Champions of Valor* | ✓ |  |
|  |  | *Fantastic Location: Hellspike Prison* |  |  |
|  | Dec | *Spell Compendium* | ✓ |  |
| 2006 | Jan | *Player's Guide to Eberron* | ✓ |  |
|  |  | *Races of the Dragon* | ✓ |  |
|  | Feb | *Red Hand of Doom* |  |  |
|  | Mar | *Power of Faerûn* |  |  |
|  |  | *Tome of Magic* | ✓ |  |
|  | Apr | *Complete Psionic* | ✓ |  |
|  |  | *Fantastic Location: Fields of Ruin* |  |  |
|  |  | *Voyage of the Golden Dragon* |  |  |
|  | May | *Player's Handbook II* | ✓ |  |
|  | Jun | *Fiendish Codex I* | ✓ |  |
|  |  | *Mysteries of the Moonsea* |  |  |
|  | Jul | *Fantastic Location: Dragondown Grotto* |  |  |
|  |  | *Monster Manual IV* | ✓ |  |
|  |  | *Secrets of Xen'drik* | ✓ |  |
|  | Aug | *Dragons of Faerûn* | ✓ | mercury, mist, steel |
|  |  | *Tome of Battle* | ✓ |  |
|  | Sep | *Dragon Magic* | ✓ |  |
|  |  | *Faiths of Eberron* | ✓ |  |
|  |  | *Twilight Tomb* |  |  |
|  | Oct | *Complete Mage* | ✓ |  |
|  |  | *Expedition to Castle Ravenloft* | ✓ |  |
|  | Nov | *Cityscape* | ✓ |  |
|  |  | *Dragonmarked* | ✓ |  |
|  |  | *Scourge of the Howling Horde* |  |  |
|  | Dec | *Animated Series Handbook* |  |  |
|  |  | *Fantastic Location: The Frostfell Rift* |  |  |
|  |  | *Fiendish Codex II* | ✓ |  |
|  |  | *Shattered Gates of Slaughtergarde* |  |  |
| 2007 | Jan | *Complete Scoundrel* | ✓ |  |
|  | Feb | *Barrow of the Forgotten King* |  |  |
|  |  | *Dungeonscape* | ✓ |  |
|  |  | *Secrets of Sarlona* | ✓ |  |
|  | Mar | *Magic Item Compendium* | ✓ |  |
|  |  | *Cormyr* |  |  |
|  | Apr | *Eyes of the Lich Queen* |  |  |
|  |  | *Expedition to the Demonweb Pits* |  |  |
|  |  | *Fantastic Location: City in Peril* |  |  |
|  | May | *Complete Champion* | ✓ |  |
|  |  | *Drow of the Underdark* | ✓ |  |
|  | Jun | *Expedition to Undermountain* |  |  |
|  |  | *Forge of War* | ✓ |  |
|  |  | *Sinister Spire* |  |  |
|  | Jul | *Monster Manual V* | ✓ | dragon characters |
|  |  | *Shadowdale* |  |  |
|  | Aug | *Expedition to the Ruins of Greyhawk* |  |  |
|  | Sep | *Exemplars of Evil* | ✓ |  |
|  |  | *Fortress of the Yuan-Ti* |  |  |
|  |  | *Grand History of the Realms* |  |  |
|  | Oct | *Dragons of Eberron* | ✓ | dragon characters |
|  |  | *Rules Compendium* | ✓ |  |
|  | Nov | *Anauroch* |  |  |
|  | Dec | *Elder Evils* | ✓ |  |
| 2008 | Feb | *City of Stormreach* | ✓ |  |
|  | Mar | *An Adventurer's Guide to Eberron* |  |  |

So it seems that the mercury dragon and steel dragon were the only additional metallic dragons to ever be published by Wizards of the Coast for D&D 3.5e, both in *Dragons of Faerûn*. Note that web articles and/or officially-licensed-but-not-WotC-published sources like *Dragon* magazine are not covered ([HeyICanChan notes in a comment](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/110297/what-kinds-of-metallic-dragons-were-ever-shown-in-dd-products/110299?noredirect=1#comment266381_110299) that *Dragon* included adamantine, chromium, iron, nickel, sodium, and tungsten dragons). And, of course, there are many books I don’t own myself to check; none of these seems very likely to have a dragon, but there are enough of them that it seems hard to claim that *none* of them do.

I cannot comment on other editions, as I do not have the resources to embark on a thorough search like this for them.

Comment: If anyone has access to a book I don’t have checked off here, feel free to check it and either let me know, or edit in a `& \checkmark` for that book yourself.

Comment: I found the same for 2e; only steel and mercury are additional metallic dragons.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast While it may be beyond this answer's mandate, *Dragondex* also lists as having been published in *Dragon* the adamantine, chromium, iron, nickel, sodium, tungsten, and rust dragons (the last may or may not warranting inclusion).

Comment: @HeyICanChan I don't think we are including the Dragon magazine "idea forum" as canon.  I prefer to limit the scope the way KRyan has ... I was reading an early Dragon issue the other day, and Kask made a very clear statement: the stuff in Dragon for OD&D and 1e, at least, was "use it if you want, or not, in your campaign."  That isn't "canon" like stuff in published books.

Comment: From Dragon Number 7:  *PUBLICATION BY THE DRAGON DOES NOT BESTOW ANY SANCTION OR APPROVAL TO ANY VARIANTS, VARIATIONS OR RULES INTERPRETATION.  The purpose of this magazine is the dissemination of information. THE DRAGON serves the field of Fantasy, Science Fiction, and Swords & Sorcery Gaming and the enthusiasts of same, in the capacity  of information source. If an article is to be considered “official,” it will be marked as such*.   (Tim Kask, Editor) (Caps are from the original).  He was indeed "shouting" at the time. (Grumpy Old Man, eh?)

Comment: @KorvinStarmast That's totally fair. (*3e* issues of *Dragon* carried a banner saying *100% Official Content* or some such… even when Paizo took over *Dragon*'s publication. I don't know if that banner was added earlier than the *3e* era, though. Further, the dragons mentioned in my comment above are primarily *3e* dragons, although some were updated from earlier editions.)

Comment: @HeyICanChan I mentioned those, anyway, since I figure they’re interesting even if not necessarily what was sought.

Comment: Updating books I haven’t checked now involves typing `|   ✓`, which is more annoying than `& \checkmark`, but you are still welcome to do so (I recommend copy ‘n’ paste). Or just comment and I can do it.